# Plotly Choropleth - How to darken state borders?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a map here that focuses on counties, which is nice, but it's hard to see the states.  Is there a way to increase width or darken the borders of the states on this map? Or any other ideas to make the map easier to read?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update subunit properties with [update_geos](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#named-map-scopes-and-country-subunits).

```
fig.update_geos(
    visible=False, resolution=110, scope="usa",
    showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="Black", subunitwidth=3
)
```